# Specify an existing SQS queue when launching an elastic beanstalk worker

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to migrate an existing cluster of processing workers on the back of an SQS queue to be deployed using elastic beanstalk. Is there a way using the `eb cli` to specify the queue either by name or id?

My current command looks like this:

```
eb create -t worker -k my-key
```

I know it is possible in the UI but that's not going to work with our CI pipeline:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with an `eb cli` option, but you can use a config file inside `.ebextensions` directory. See example:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:sqsd
    option_name: WorkerQueueURL
    value: YOUR-QUEUE-URL
```

Here you can see related discussion: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=706191

Here is documentation for the option: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elasticbeanstalksqsd

Comment: Hi @stibi, I have added the config file with the above lines. But getting error. ERROR: "option_settings" in one of the configuration files failed validation. More details to follow.
ERROR: Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:sqsd', OptionName: 'https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/038080997316/vp-test-q'): Unknown configuration setting.
ERROR: Failed to launch environment.